# Vertical scroll bar with 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue here. Simple layout with header, nav bar, and content divs inside of a container with 100% height, but I'm still getting a vertical scroll bar.

style.css

```
html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
background: #E6E6E6;
}

#container{
width: 900px;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
left: 450px;
}

#header{
width: 900px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#navBar{
width: 900px;
height:20px;
position: absolute;
top: 77px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#content{
width: 900px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 104px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Show us the corresponding HTML as well.

Comment: how about `overflow:hidden` in that container where you dont want a scrollbar?

Comment: Doing that removes the border on one side.

Comment: with this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/eevzvsdL/) I don't see a vertical scroll - only a horizontal one

Comment: @Danield Correct, but your example is missing the 100% which needs to be applied to both html and body, see http://jsfiddle.net/eevzvsdL/1/ which indeed has vertical scrollbars.

Comment: @Paul - but the OP doesn't have that in his code. Using *his* code no vertical scrollbars are present

Comment: Please mark one answer as right, if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

according to your comment about `overflow: hidden` removing a border try this:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

that only removes the vertical scrollbar, like you asked.

Comment: It's a wild guess, but I think he is talking about the bottom border.

Comment: could be, this is still worth the try though.

Comment: Sure, since OP didn't provide the HTML structure yet, it's kinda hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #header, #navbar and #content are children of container, the reason is quite obvious. #content is also set to 100% height and additionally has a top value. So, it's full height and then shifted down, of course resulting in a vertical scrollbar.

One solution would be to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to #container, but that would just cut the content. You need to calculate the height correctly:

```
#content { height: calc(100% - 106px); }
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1n602vco/)***.

Additional information: I substract 106px due to the top margin of 104 plus 2px for the borders.

Comment: Doing this with the content-inner method makes my header and nav bar disappear

Comment: this will cause problems in old browsers, because they dont know "calc"

Answer (score 0):

your `height: 100%` in the `#container {` causes this problem.
if you want to fix this, you have to set `bottom: 0`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eevzvsdL/3/)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    height: 100%; /* added this to html,body*/
}
#content{
    width: 900px;
    bottom: 0; /* set this instead of height: 100%*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 104px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```